# Android Studio v1.4 preview 2 not able to install app on Phone

Tags: android, android-studio

After upgrading android studio to 1.4 preview 2 using Canary Channel and since then AS is behaving a little differently. It is not able to install the app on phone. It is getting stuck at following line:

```
Uploading file
    local path: /Volumes/project/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.sample.android
Installing com.sample.android
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.sample.android"
```

Any suggestions what could be wrong. I have restarted the AS, also my machine but AS is stuck in same mode.

PS : i understand the canary channel provides latest stuff and it maybe broken but i am assuming that it wont break the basic app installing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get a timeout error message?
after the line

> DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.sample.android"

For me the problem was I got timeout error, and after replacing the USB  cable, it solved the problem,

Comment: I checked the Event Log, i am not getting timeout error. It is just stuck there.